# how to get simple search in rails based on RailsCasts tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I followed the RailsCasts tutorial to do a simple search with autocomplete, but it doesn't work. :(

view/vendors/index:

```
<% form_tag vendors_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_with_auto_complete   :vendor, 
                                        :name,
                                        {}, 
                                        {:method => :get, :class => 'textbox'} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= @searchvendor.id %>
<%= @searchterm %>
```

I included @searchterm and @searchvendor.id as validation steps.

So this should call the controller => vendor, action=> index:

```
def index
    @searchterm = params[:vendor][:name]

    @searchvendor = Vendor.search('checkpoint')
```

And the search method is created as follows for the vendor/model:

```
  def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
```

The output?

@searchterm does show the value that is inputed as that shows up in the URL as vendor[name]=?

@searchvendor.id is a long string and @searchvendor.name shows an error, name not a method.

I'm stumped.  Help...please?

LINK to the Tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Comment: You may want to add a link to the tutorial you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Should you not be passing in your @searchterm into your Vendor.search method? Passing 'checkpoint' each time probably isn't going to do the trick.
2. @searchvendor is going to contain an Array as you are doing find(:all). You'll need to iterate over the array and do .name on each item.

Comment: right, it was passing it -- I changed it and cut/paste wrong code to do a sanity check...however, #2 seems like what is the problem...!!  Will try that out first!

Comment: okay, I am passing params[:name] and tried params[:vendor][:name] which seemed to make sense but that bombed.

Comment: Bombed in what way? Have you used a debugger (like the one in Netbeans) to check the value of params[:name], params[:vendor][:name] or just params?