# SQLite3::SQLException Implementing Search Function In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, search, sqlite

I am working on a search function in Rails. I followed the following tutorial

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

I have therefore updated my tutorial.rb with the following

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Updating my tutorials_controller.rb with the following

```
def index
  @tutorials = Tutorial.search(params[:search])
end
```

Finally my view with

```
<div id="search">
      <%= form_tag tutorials_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "btn btn-success" %>
     </p>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

So it is all displaying. When I hit the search box I get the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TutorialsController#index

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "tutorials".* FROM "tutorials"  WHERE     (name LIKE '%%')
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Still new to this and a little our of my depth. I can see that it is having problem getting information from the database but not sure how to cure it.

Cheers!

Comment: [That particular tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) is almost seven years old. It is very likely that things have changed in the interim.

Comment: Should have seen that! Thanks for pointing that out. Any better sources?

Comment: This could help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827914/how-to-get-simple-search-in-rails-based-on-railscasts-tutorial?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As per the error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name`,
there is no column `name` in the `tutorials` table.

If you intended to search the `tutorials` table based on `name` field then add it to the `tutorials` table with a migration:

`rails g migration AddNameToTutorial name`

run `rake db:migrate`

Insert some records in Tutorial table with names.

Then, go ahead and `search` based on name field in `tutorials` table with your current code.

---

Second option is, if you intended to search `tutorials` table based on some other `existing field` then just update the search method as below:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['fieldname LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

where replace `fieldname` with the attribute name that you want to search on.